# How to find out status of a usb device using c#?

Tags: c#

i am creating a project related to power consumed by our computer systems.
now my requirement is ,
 i need to find out power consumed by a usb device(like pendrive) in the system.
can anybody plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can because the USB specification seems not to mention anything about delivering those measurements. The only information I know you can get is if the device is a low-power or high-power device. For [USB 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus) that is 100mA or 500mA with a voltage between 4.4 and 5.25V. So a low-power power device may consume from almost 0 to 5.25*0.1=0,525W and a high-power up to 5.25*0.5=2.625W.

Unfortunately the WMI classes doesn't seem to give you even that information but that could be just me looking at the wrong places.

```
//using System.Management
var USBDevices = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice");
foreach (var device in USBDevices.Get())
{
    foreach (var prop in device.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + " : " + prop.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you enter `using System.Management` at the top and did you add a reference to it in the project?

Comment: Also this was only an example of how to get information with the Windows Management Instrumentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx as you can see I didn't actually find the information you were looking for. It could still be there somewhere.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not and I also believe you will not be able to get the information you're looking for with software only. Most problably you will need to measure the power consumption externally. http://www.tomsguide.com/us/squeezing-more-life-out-of-your-notebook,review-583-26.html

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/default.aspx
An USB library by the creators of SharpDevelop (at least on the same server)